# Changing rows to columns in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, split

Basically, we have a .txt-file containing a table that is tab separated like the following one (`___` represents a tab):

```
Name___Phone___City

Person1___111-111-1111___City1

Person2___222-222-2222___City2
```

We want to output another .txt-file that should contain the following:

```
Name, Person1, Person2

Phone, 111-111-1111, 222-222-2222

City, City1, City2
```

I tired using `string.split()` but couldn't produce the desired result. How can I do the above presented transformation with JavaScript?

Comment: Don't know what language you're using but just use `string.replace("\t", ", ")`

Comment: string.split should work. could you please show the output and your code?

Comment: Welcome on SO. I have edited your question to add formatting and added an actual question. Please [edit] your question further to include the code you already tried, the problems you encountered and the output you could generate.

Answer (score 0):

Again no clue what language you're using, here's a one liner that works from any terminal as long as perl is installed (`Unix` based systems automatically, available on windows as well through download)

```
perl -pi -e 's/\t/, /g' /path/to/file
```

Comment: I am using javascript.

Comment: if you want a decent js answer, you'll have to specify your exact code, where it goes wrong, what platform (nodejs / browser) you're working from and why my proposed solution -> `string = string.replace("\t", ", ")` isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would do is get the lines using this Regex `/(.+)\n?/`. Then, in each line, I'd split & join on the three underscores.

```
function reorder(input){
    var regex = /(.+)\n?/gm, m, output = '';
    while (m = regex.exec(input)) output += m[1].split('___').join(', ') + '\n';
    return output;
};
```

Not sure you can write to a file in JavaScript though; maybe in Node.js?